# How to remove multiple elements from arrays of an array using GAS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, multidimensional-array

**The problem**

I have a dataset encompassing empty columns. This dataset is obtained by `getValues()` of a defined range. Since I'll be storing this data set, I'd like to remove empty columns prior to that and, therefore, these columns need to be removed.

**Dataset Sample**

```
[
["120/1","2022-02-01T03:00:00.000Z","2022-02-01T03:00:00.000Z","Cartão Crédito","","Sicredi","","Visa","","1 + 6x","","1 de 7",100],
["120/2","2022-02-01T03:00:00.000Z","2022-03-01T03:00:00.000Z","Cartão Crédito","","Sicredi","","Visa","","1 + 6x","","2 de 7",100]
]
```

**The evil code snippet** (to me)

```
const colsVazias = [11, 9, 7, 5];//"Columns/elements" to be removed
    for (let i = colsVazias.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      for (let r = 0; r < pagtos.length; r++) {
        pagtos[r].splice(colsVazias[i], 1)
      }
    }
```

I have also tried this one (borrowed from @nnnnnn), but I can't tweak it to meet the demand here. Most likely, because we're dealing with different dimensions here...

```
var valuesArr = ["v1","v2","v3","v4","v5"],
    removeValFromIndex = [0,2,4];    

for (var i = removeValFromIndex.length -1; i >= 0; i--)
   valuesArr.splice(removeValFromIndex[i],1);
```

**Expected output:**

```
[
["120/1","2022-02-01T03:00:00.000Z","2022-02-01T03:00:00.000Z","Cartão Crédito","Sicredi","Visa","1 + 6x","1 de 7",100],
["120/2","2022-02-01T03:00:00.000Z","2022-03-01T03:00:00.000Z","Cartão Crédito","Sicredi","Visa","1 + 6x","2 de 7",100]
]
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple map/filter combo would do it

```js
let pagatos = [
["120/1","2022-02-01T03:00:00.000Z","2022-02-01T03:00:00.000Z","Cartão Crédito","","Sicredi","","Visa","","1 + 6x","","1 de 7",100],
["120/2","2022-02-01T03:00:00.000Z","2022-03-01T03:00:00.000Z","Cartão Crédito","","Sicredi","","Visa","","1 + 6x","","2 de 7",100]
];

let remove = [10, 8, 6, 4]
pagatos = pagatos.map(p => p.filter((v,i) => !remove.includes(i)))
console.log(pagatos)
```

Comment: Hello, Kinglish! Pretty neat! How to have these to be removed elements' indexes specified and make sure we will remove them only. The way it is, I suppose that if the entry is not there, it'll filter it out as well, correct? I'd need to avoid that... Thank you!

Comment: I updated my answer. Note your original `remove` array was not zero indexed (needs to be). I adjusted it here.

Comment: Right on! Thank you!